# Passing an input argument to Matlab SDK function from C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I created a C library using Matlab Compiler SDK, but am not able to pass an input argument to it.

The function definition in Matlab is like this, so it takes one argument, which I'm assuming to be double.

```
function out = test7(in)
    out = double(in);
end
```

In the C++ header, the input arguments are like this.

```
extern LIB_libtest7_C_API bool MW_CALL_CONV mlfTest7(int nargout, mxArray** out, mxArray* in);
```

So, my question boils down to how to 'convert' a C++ double variable to an mxArray so that it can be passed to the function. For example, if I had  `double num = 1.2;`, how can I input this?

As for  `int nargout` and  `mxArray** out`, I know how to handle them.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I just tried what was suggested in a comment, and am trying to create a matrix like this. However, the line with memcpy(...) results in segmentation fault(core dumped) at execuion.

```
    mxArray* d[1];
    double pr_data[] = {2.2};
    double  *start_of_pr;
    mxArray *array_ptr;
    array_ptr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);

    start_of_pr = (double*)mxGetPr(array_ptr);
    memcpy(start_of_pr, pr_data, sizeof(double));

    libtest7Initialize();
    mlfTest7(1, d1, array_ptr);
```

P.S.2 Following the suggestion in the comment, I modified my code as below, but unfortunately I still get the segmentation fault error.

```
int main(){
    mxArray* d[1];
    double pr_data[] = {2.2};
    mxArray *array_ptr;
    array_ptr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    *mxGetPr(array_ptr) = 2.2; // this line leads to segmentation fault
//    libtest7Initialize();
//    mlfTest7(1, d, array_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried this.

```
int main(){
    mxArray* d[1];
    double pr_data[] = {2.2};
    mxCreateDoubleScalar: mxArray* array_ptr = mxCreateDoubleScalar(2.2);
    libtest7Initialize();
    mlfTest7(1, d, array_ptr); // this line produces a different error.
    return 0;
}
```

And now mlfTest7(1, d, array_ptr) produces this error at execution.

[image]

P.S.3
As for the last bit of the code, the build log looks like this, just to show how the code is built.

```
-------------- Build: Debug in 10MayTest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -Iapplication -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/extern/include/ -c /home/kazuya/Documents/10MayTest/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++ -Lapplication -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/extern/include -L/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v910/runtime/glnxa64/ -L/home/kazuya/Documents/10MayTest -o bin/Debug/10MayTest obj/Debug/main.o   -lmwmclmcrrt -ltest7
In file included from /home/kazuya/Documents/10MayTest/libtest7.h:16,
                 from /home/kazuya/Documents/10MayTest/main.cpp:3:
/home/kazuya/Documents/10MayTest/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/extern/include/mclmcrrt.h:7125:34: warning: label ‘mxCreateDoubleScalar_800_proxy’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 7125 | #define mxCreateDoubleScalar_800 mxCreateDoubleScalar_800_proxy
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021a/extern/include/matrix.h:386:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘mxCreateDoubleScalar_800’
  386 | #define mxCreateDoubleScalar mxCreateDoubleScalar_800
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/kazuya/Documents/10MayTest/main.cpp:19:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘mxCreateDoubleScalar’
   19 |     mxCreateDoubleScalar: mxArray* array_ptr = mxCreateDoubleScalar(2.2);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Output file is bin/Debug/10MayTest with size 30.23 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: In my answer to your previous question I shared a link to the [C Matrix API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cc-mx-matrix-library.html). Did you look at that? There are functions there to create a matrix.

Comment: Oh thanks. I've tried this and am now facing an issue.

Comment: To write a single double value, you should be able to do this: `*mxGetPr(array_ptr) = 2.2;`.

Comment: Right after `mxArray *array_ptr;`, I added `*mxGetPr(array_ptr) = 2.2;`, which results in segmentation fault. Sorry to ask basic stuff, but can you tell me how I should integrate that line to the code?

Comment: It was a suggestion to replace `memcpy`. You still need to use `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` to allocate the mxArray. Note that `mxArray *array_ptr` declares the `array_ptr` variable, but assigns no value to it. Thus you cannot dereference it. You must assign a value (the pointer to an mxArray) to it first.

Comment: You can also use `mxCreateDoubleScalar`: `mxArray* array_ptr = mxCreateDoubleScalar(2.2);`. And I just learned there is also a `mxGetScalar` function that would simplify the code in the other question a little bit.

Comment: How do you build your program? The code itself is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0);` was necessary at the beginning. By adding this, the two suggestions worked. Just as an example,

```
#include "libtest7.h"


int main(){
    mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0); // this was necessary

    mxArray* d[1];
    double pr_data[] = {2.2};
    mxArray *array_ptr;
    array_ptr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
    *mxGetPr(array_ptr) = 2.2;
    libtest7Initialize();
    mlfTest7(1, d, array_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```